# Why RAID controllers so expensive?

Tags: hardware-raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are hardware RAID solutions relatively expensive?](https://superuser.com/questions/376376/why-are-hardware-raid-solutions-relatively-expensive)

Well, this maybe a very stupid question. Shouldn't RAID controllers be very simple? Compare RAID controller with Linux-based network router, or MPEG decoders, I can't believe a RAID controller needs more technique. Why it's so complex and expensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just supply and demand. The market for RAID controllers is much smaller than the market for routers or MPEG decoders.

Comment: On top of that, such products do not require the kind of performance RAID users demand. Performance = money.

Comment: True. Your average SOHO router doesn't have to process 6Gb/s.

Answer (score 4):

RAID controllers deal with higher bandwidth and lower latency data streams than your typical network router, and don't have the option of just throwing away data like a router does.  I expect much more from any sort of disk controller than I do from a network router.